# RLC circuit, at what frequencies is the current 0.8A

Tags: passive-networks

[image: RLC]

So I want to know at what frequencies the current is 0.8A.
I've calculated the resonance freq to =1006.6 Hz and the current is at that point 1A.

So if I understand this correctly there will be 2 frequencies on each side of the resonance and at the same distance that will have the 0.8A current.

Is my understanding correct? if so, how do I calculate these frequencies?

Comment: I = V/sqrt((R^2)+(Xl-Xc)^2) this gives 0.8 = 10/(sqrt(10^2+((2 * Pi * f * 2.5e-3)-(1/2 * Pi * f * 10e-6))^2)), solve for f.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your understanding is correct.

You know that the magnitude of the circuit impedance needs to be 12.5 ohms for the current to be 0.8A.

So, write down the equation for the magnitude of the total impedance of all three components as a function of frequency, set it equal 12.5 ohms, and solve for f. It's a quadratic equation, so you will indeed get two answers.

Comment: 1kHz +/- 477.943 Hz.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the RLC network's impedance for an unknown frequency, then calculate the current through it using the input voltage and the impedance. This will give you the current as a function of frequency which you can then solve for f by setting it equal to 0.8A.

Answer (score 0):

You need an impedance of 12.5 ohms to obtain 0.8 amps. Given that there is an immutable resistance of 10 ohms, you need to know what reactive impedance is in series to produce an overall impedance of 12.5 ohms. This calculation relies on the difference of squares i.e. Reactance is \$\sqrt{12.5^2-10^2}\$ = 7.5 ohms.

Then ask yourself what frequencies give you a net impedance magnitude of 7.5 ohms when you have 2.5 mH in series with 10 uF. Fairly easy.